# Purpose of GetCapabilities and GetMap requests in WMS server

Tags: wms, getcapabilities, getmap

What is the purpose of GetCapabilities and GetMap request in WMS server? Like how they work when a request is being made to them.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being an online GIS tutor.

Answer (score 3):

The GetCapabilities gives you the capabilities of the service. It tells you the operations supported, the names of the layers, the styles of the layers, the coordinate reference systems supported, the media formats supported, any restrictions on display scale, the bounding boxes of the layers, and can give supplementary information about the data that make up the layers.

GetCapabilities is an operation common to all OGC services not just WMS.

GetMap is the operation to create a map, according to the ingredients you choose, from the GetCapabilities response *menu*.